# create R studio shortcut for %in%

Tags: r, rstudio

I'd like to create a keyboard shortcut in R studio for: %in%.  I know I can do this by going into Tools > Modify Keyboard Shortcuts, but I don't know what this is called.  Any thoughts?

Comment: In `SAS` it is called as `in operator` and since in R as well it does the same function as in SAS so we could call it the same

Comment: @jkatam thanks!  But I'm actually looking for what it is called in the Keyboard Shortcut menu, because that's the only way I can assign a shortcut.  For example %>% is named "Insert Pipe Operator"; it's not the name I gave it, but what Rstudio calls that shortcut.

Comment: i checked the R documentation and it is just called as `%in% operator`

Comment: @jkatam, I'm sure you're correct, but unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be an option in the menu.

Comment: I checked further on this and it is called as `infix operator`

Comment: @jkatam no, that also isn't in the list.